# Is there a public API for StackExchange?

Tags: support, feature-request, stackexchange, api

I was thinking it would be nice to have an appindicator for StackExchange that would change color for a few seconds when an answer or question is voted up or down, etc. It would display your reputation, the most recent badges, a list of the most recently affected questions and it would provide a list of the n newest unseen questions. The latter can be easily implemented by using webfeeds. But what about the other things? Is there an API for that -- perhaps even for Python?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/stackapplet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is, you can find it on each of the sites at https://api.stackexchange.com/

You can also find a slew of tools, libraries, and apps built by other users on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/)